# curl to tar to zip not working properly

Tags: command-line, tar, curl, zip, extract

I am wanting to download an `tar.gz` archive, extract it and compress it into a `zip` file in one command. Reason for this is to be independent from temporary files.

The command I use:

```
curl -L "someURL" | tar xOzf - | zip -qr > /home/username/filename.zip
```

gives me a zip File that contains a file named `-`.

Removing the `-` from the tar command leaves me with an zip file only containing a small portion of the downloaded file, while beeing a very large archive.

Maybe I am missing something out here...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extracting downloaded files to standard output using `-O` option with `tar` you can extract the downloaded archive with `-v` option.

It will print the extracted filenames with their full path in standard output, pipe that to zip. Your job will be done.

```
curl -L "http://someurl/some.tar.gz" | tar xvzf - | zip -qr /path/to/myfile.zip -@
```

Here **file list** is specified as `-@`, zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead of from the command line. To know more about zip see [`man zip`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/zip.1.html)

Contents of `myfile.zip` will be as below:

```
myfile.zip
└──some
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    └── folder
        ├── file4
        ├── file5
        ├── file6
        └── file7
```

Every files and folders are inside parent folder `some` which is in  zip's root.

### How to the put all files and folders in the zip's root

As [OP asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/523736/curl-to-tar-to-zip-not-working-properly/523780?noredirect=1#comment713728_523780) to have all files to be in the zip's root, unlike the above case where all those files and folders were inside a folder that was in zip's root.

Use the following,

```
curl -L "http://someurl/some.tar.gz" | tar xvzf - --strip-components=1 && zip -qr /path/to/myfile.zip *
```

It will create contents of `myfile.zpi` as following:

```
myfile.zip
    ├── file1
    ├── file2
    ├── file3
    └── folder
        ├── file4
        ├── file5
        ├── file6
        └── file7
```

The option `--strip-components=1` with `tar` do not extract the first component of the archive i.e., the parent folder. So all the files and folders get extracted in current folder.

You might want to do it inside an empty temporary folder. So that after creating the zip file you can clean the residue.

Comment: Thank you, it does almost what I need it to do, but it doesn't output the zip file into the folder I wan't it to be. Could you please tell me what the `-@` does in this context?

Comment: Also inside the zip is a folder that contains all the files, but I need the files to be in the zip's root.